# Unicode Disappearing in html.parser

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, python-3.x, python-unicode

I am extracting HTML from some webpage with Unicode characters as follows:

```
def extract(url):
     """ Adapted from Python3_Google_Search.py """
     user_agent = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) "
                   "AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML,     like Gecko)"
                   "Chrome/0.2.149.29 Safari/525.13")
     request = urllib.request.Request(url)
     request.add_header("User-Agent",user_agent)
     response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
     html = response.read().decode("utf8")
     return html
```

I am decoding properly as you can see. So `html` is now a unicode string. When printing html, I can see the Unicode characters.

I am using `html.parser` to parse the HTML and subclassed it:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
class Parser(HTMLParser):
  def __init__(self):
    ## some init stuff
  #### rest of class
```

When parsing out the HTML using the class's `handle_data`, it appears that the Unicode characters are removed/suddenly disappear. The docs do not mention anything about encodings. Why does HTML Parser remove non-ascii characters, and how can I fix such an issue?

Comment: what program/tool are you using to view the output?

Comment: 1. Are you 100% certain that the data your script receives has the characters there, and 2. how are you verifying that the non-ascii characters have 'disappeared'?

Comment: I used Emacs in Terminal (has Unicode encoding on) and then again Mac TextEdit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, when I print `html` before returning in the `extract` function, I see this: `<td>&Ouml;sterreich</td>`. So yes, I'm 100% certain my script received the right unicode characters.

I am verifying that the unicode characters have disappeared by opening the text file I wrote out to and seeing them not there.

Comment: @Darksky: Those are HTML escape codes, using *only* ASCII characters. Something else is removing those, this has nothing to do with Python so far. `&Ouml;` is 6 characters, an ampersand, a capital `O`, lowercase `u`, `m` and `l`, then a semicolon.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I found out the problem. I am using this html to feed into a `html.parser` subclass, using: `parser.feed(html)`. They are disappearing there.

Comment: @Darksky: Then update your question to be about *that subclass*.

Comment: Do you call `super().__init__()` at all in your custom subclass?

Comment: Nope. Do I have to? I think I figured it out. I'm writing a response. Python's documentation is so, so bad it's ridiculous.

Comment: @Darksky: Also, the *rest* of the custom parser might very well be relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `html.parser` will call `handle_entityref` whenever it encounters a non-ascii character. It passes the named character reference, and to convert that to the unicode character, I used:

```
html.entities.html5[name]
```

Python's documentation does not mention that. I've never seen worse documentation that Python.